# getting error in taking input from file in c

Tags: c, visual-studio, file, unistd.h

I want to take input from a file in c++. I am using Visual studio 2015. My sample code function for taking input from file is:

```
#define INPUT_FILE_NAME "input.txt"
#define V 15
int total number=0;   
double px[V];
double py[V];      
void fileInput()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char cwd[1024];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL)   //Directory not found
    {
        perror("getcwd() error - Current directory not found !!");
        exit(0);
    }
    strcat(cwd, "\\");
    strcat(cwd, INPUT_FILE_NAME);
    fp = fopen(cwd, "r");

    int i = 0;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &start);
    while (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &px[i]) != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", &py[i]);
        i++;
        total_number++;
    }
}
```

My input file format is as follows:

```
2
0 1
2 1
```

But when I compile, I get an error like: identifier 'getcwd' is undefined. Is there any way to replace this function, so that I can get the same output?

Comment: Did you include the required header files?

Comment: Not completely related, but this is `C` not `C++`

Comment: I have included <unistd.h> but getting error in that @Rakete1111

Comment: Please check the return value from `fopen` before you even use the file pointer. And please post your actual code, which this is not (`start` is not defined). See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235450.aspx) `getcwd` is deprecated and the suggested replacement `_getcwd` is defined in `<direct.h>`

Comment: @UnholySheep: `void fileInput()` is probably C++, it would be `void fileInput(void)` in C, unless of course there is no compile-time argument checking required.

Comment: Why do you need `getcwd` at all? Just use `INPUT_FILE_NAME` as your file name: `fopen(INPUT_FILE_NAME, "r");`.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. If you are writing in C++, throw away all of this and learn C++ APIs. If you are writing in C, use `void fileInput(void)`.

Comment: You have to check return values of library functions you call. Also, reading two numbers is `fscanf(fp, "%ld%ld", &px[i], &py[i])`. It returns the number of items successfully scanned. Thus, `while(fscanf(fp, "%ld%ld", &px[i], &py[i]) == 2) { ... }`

Comment: @cdarke you are correct, I missed that (as I was mainly looking at the body of the function). Although I guess that would also be one of the more common mistakes of beginners in C.

Answer (score 0):

try the header #include "direct.h" it might be why...

Comment: These kind of answers are better suited for comments than real answers.